# VueJS 3 + Node v14: Buffer is not defined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I have this code to convert string to base64

```
convertToBase64(string) {
        try {
            if (!string) {
                return;
            }
            debugger
            if (Buffer && typeof Buffer.from == "function") {
                const buff = Buffer.from(string);
                const base64 = buff.toString('base64');
                return base64;
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
```

> And I got this error: "Buffer is not defined".
> Node version: v14.16.0
> Npm version: 6.14.11

I tried reinstalling Nodejs but it doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: Where is this one called? Buffer is probably a server only thing, hence why you get the error on the front-end. Also, it's not related but the current version of Node's LTS is 16, please upgrade to it now rather than working on an obsolete one (I recommend using nvm).

Comment: I tried it in Node v16 but nothing changed. I use it instead of atob/btoa (front-end). Any thing wrong here?

Comment: Yeah it's not a Node.js version issue as I said. Where do you run your code? You can only use given methods if they are available in your environment.

Comment: I call this method from my javascript file name : CommonFunc.js. But nothing diff when I move this code to .vue file

Comment: then I config it global like this: ```app.config.globalProperties.$commonFunc = CommonFunc```

Comment: TL;DR: you can't use Node code in browser app.